# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.templates'

Tags: python, django

Recently I made a django project and it was working fine.

But after I added "Map"app to my project, there was an error like title of my question.

So I erased all of the "Map"app and didn't touch anything.
But the error still did not go away.

I tried to change "templates" from "settings.py" to "template" by referring to other questions, but the error did not go away.

Somebody help me.......plz...........

"settings.py"

```
    """
Django settings for delibrary project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'l(gh10dpuv42dt4twx)xpvu-!d60=!6pm$geh7jc6s*#)o%p%3'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'library',
    'cart',
    'orders',
    'accounts',


]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'delibrary.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.templates.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.templates.context_processors.debug',
                'django.templates.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'cart.context_processors.cart',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'delibrary.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

CART_SESSION_ID = 'cart'
```

"urls.py"

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),
    path('order/', include('orders.urls', namespace='orders')),
    path('', include('library.urls', namespace='library')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

When I typed "templates"(settings.py TEMPLATES)

[image]

When I typed "template"

[image]

this is my error

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 11, 2020 - 12:23:10
Django version 3.0.4, using settings 'delibrary.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\real of real\delibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\real of real\delibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\real of real\delibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\real of real\delibrary\library\views.py", line 9, in book_list
    return render(request, 'library/books/list.html', {'books': books})
  File "C:\real of real\delibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\real of real\delibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\real of real\delibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\real of real\delibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 169, in render
    with context.bind_template(self):
  File "C:\PYTHON\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\real of real\delibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py", line 242, in bind_template
    processors = (template.engine.template_context_processors +
  File "C:\real of real\delibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\real of real\delibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 85, in template_context_processors
    return tuple(import_string(path) for path in context_processors)
  File "C:\real of real\delibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 85, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(import_string(path) for path in context_processors)
  File "C:\real of real\delibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\PYTHON\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.templates'
[11/May/2020 12:23:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 126914
```

T_T...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no path like `django.templates` but **`django.template`** (without **`s`**). I am not sure how that comes to **`django.templates`** in your settings since it is auto-generated by the Django itself.

So, change anything that referes *`django.templates`* to **`django.template`** will solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you sir !! I didn't notice anything else was "templates"!, I fixed it!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.py` you can remove `s` from:

```
'BACKEND': 'django.templates.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
```

So it will be:

```
'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
```

Just this.